# React Native OneSignal + iOS - device does not subscribe

Tags: react-native, certificate, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

I follow all the steps of documentation but nothing works
1 - Create a free account on OneSignal
2 - Use onesignal tool to generate the certificate and upload the .p12 file
3 - Initialize react-native-onesignal SDK in the code

The device asks for permission to push notifications but does not subscribe on the OneSignal Dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be several reasons,

- iPhone Simulator is unable to receive push notifications so better use a physical device.
- Sometimes device id is not detected so it does not subscribe. Check this https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal/issues/200

in your case, it is hard to explain without source code.